# OpenVPN to home network connections not working on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, ssh, vpn

I'm using PIVPN with OpenVPN to connect to my home network anywhere in the world.

I have three profiles, one for my iPhone and one for my MacBook Pro and one for a windows laptop.

When I connect to my VPN from either my iPhone or my Windows laptop outside my network, I can successfully connect to my home server via SSH etc.

However, when I connect to the VPN from my MacBook, everything works, like normal browsing and I have my home networks IP address. I just can't ping my home devices or SSH into my server through the connection.

In conclusion, this makes me believe that it is a macOS problem as everything is working on two other devices and my Mac can connect to the vpn, just can't do things that I want it too, like SSH.

I am running macOS Big Sur

Comment: facing the same issue, did you find the workaround?

Comment: @RockyBalboa I have not.... Still searching the whole of Google's index trying to find answers. It may be Big Sur?

Comment: Yes, this is the because of BigSur, what I did is reinstalled Catalina and everything started working. Some people have noticed this and I think OpenVPN needs to update their app to run on BigSur and for that time being, I rolled back. Meanwhile on apple's VPN apps are working on BigSur. Here is the link for more: http://shorturl.at/cnBGU
http://shorturl.at/zMRT3

Comment: @RockyBalboa It is now working, just to let you know :)